# MYSQL Search for matching letters within term

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a database with property details in, I'm attempting to search a column with short versions of properties such as 1KC, 2KC, 12GH. I am wanting to be able to search for KC and it display 1KC, 2KC, 3KC rows. But what I have will only work with exact matches.

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","SAGE");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{echo "<option value='MYSQL ERROR'>Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error() . "</option>";}
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM property_terms WHERE MATCH(MARKETING_ABR) AGAINST ('1KC');");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{echo "<option value='". $row['PROPERTY_ABR'] ."'>" . $row['ADDRES_1'] . "</option>";}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Is it possible for it to match with just KC? I have updated the my.cnf to add ft_min_word_len = 1, but still no luck, any help would be great!

Comment: Did you `Then restart the server and rebuild your FULLTEXT indexes` after modifying the `my.cnf`? -http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html

Comment: Yes, I've done this twice, just incase! If I use the above, and then search for just KC (to then show 1KC, 2KC...), I get no results

Comment: What about using LIKE with WHERE clause ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the following. The `%` at the beginning means that it doesn't matter what is in front of `$search`. The `%` at the end means that it doesn't matter what is at the end.

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `property_terms` WHERE `column` LIKE '%$search%'");
```